# How do I compare two 4 digit numbers for below conditions in Python?

Tags: python, comparison

There is this game I am trying to code in Python.

A random generated 4 digit number with different digits, will be compared to the user input number of the same properties (4 digit, different digits).

Is there a short way of comparing both numbers to evaluate and return to the user the following:

1. How many digits match in both numbers that are in the same decimal place in both numbers.
2. How  many digits match in both numbers that are in different decimal places.

Output will be +1 for each of the condition 1 above and -1 for the condition 2; indicating; "+" sign for right place and the following number after "+" is for the number of right place digits; "-" sign for the wrong place and the following number after the "-" sign is for the misplaced digits that are in the number to be guessed.

example: for computer's number 1234

guess1: 1572
feedback1: +1 -1

guess2: 1039
feedback2: +2 -0

guess3: 1243
feedback3: +2 -2

And this goes on until the feedback is +4 -0, which returns the user guessed the number in x tries and he/she is a complete idiot:)

I did this in 70 coding lines (just the first guess comparison part) or so and since I don't know the first thing about coding, I am sure there is a better way to do it. Several times I had to convert the number(s) into strings and back to integers while doing so.

Most probably, I don't know the command to use and how to use it to simplify things, so I almost if/elif/else'd the whole thing one by one.(emphasize on almost:)) What little I know, I have learned from the Python documentation online and from here.

What is the proper short way of doing it? Just the comparison of/testing of both numbers part will be enough to get me going more optimistically.

```
# 4 digit number guessing game

import random, sys
import pygame as pg # not used
from pygame.locals import * #not used
import time
import os#realized later on that if this is not there, I can't specify a 
ValueError.


#pygame init()not necessary for the time being
global tahmin#don't know why I put this here. tried to overcome the error I 
got saying the variable is referenced before it is assigned by changing the 
variable into a global one. But did not work unless I wrote this line into 
the function it is called. But since no harm done, I kept it here.
global sayı#same as above

def pick():#computer picks a number between min and max different 4 digit 
range.
    global sayı#above mentioned story
    sayı = random.randint(1023, 9876)
    sayı = str(sayı)

def testpick(): #testing the number generated by the computer for different 
digits
    while True:
        if sayı[0] == sayı[1] or sayı[0] == sayı[2] or sayı[0] == sayı[3] or sayı[1] == sayı[2] or sayı[1] == sayı[3] or sayı[2] == sayı[3]:    
            print("geçersiz sayı")#invalid number
            print("değiştiriyorum")#changing the number
            pick()
            print(sayı[0]+sayı[1]+sayı[2]+sayı[3])#just for testing for 
myself
        else:
            #tahmin_gir() cancelled
            print("Sayımı tuttum")#Picked my number
            break

def tahmin_gir():#input guess function
    global tahmin#same story above
    try:#make sure it is a number
        tahmin = int(input("Tahminini gir==>"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sadece sayı girebilirsin!")
        tahmin_gir()
    

def tahmin_test():#test the guess function
    global tahmin#blody global same story above
    tahmin_gir()
    if tahmin >= 1023 and tahmin <= 9876:
        tahmin = str(tahmin)
        if tahmin[0] == tahmin[1] or tahmin[0] == tahmin[2] or tahmin[0] == tahmin[3] or tahmin[1] == tahmin[2] or tahmin[1] == tahmin[3] or tahmin[2] == tahmin[3]:
            print("Basamaklar birbirinden farklı olmalı!")#Digits must be 
different
            tahmin_test()
    elif tahmin < 0:
        print("Pozitif bir sayı gir !")#must be positive number
        tahmin_test()   
    else:
        print("Sayı 4 basamaklı olmalı !")#must be 4 digits
        tahmin_test()
    
print("Lütfen adını gir ve enter'a bas.")#name and enter

ad = input()
# mics. explaining the game below
print("Merhabalar! " + ad + " 4 basamaklı, basamakları birbirinden farklı 
bir sayı tuttum.")

print("Bakalım kaç denemede bulabileceksin.")

print("Sana her tahmininden sonra geri bildirimler yapacağım.")

print("Örneğin tuttuğum 1234 sayısı için, senin yaptığın tahmin 1562 
olsun.")

print("Benim sana cevabım +1 -1 olacaktır. Bunun anlamı, tahmininde 1 adet 
doğru sayı doğru yerde,")
print("1 adet de, doğru sayı yanlış yerde. Yani tahmininde baştaki 1 sayısı 
hem sayımın içinde var, hem de yeri")
print("doğru. Bunun için +1. Sondaki 2 sayısı da sayımda var ama yeri doğru 
değil. Bunun için de -1")

print("2. tahminde 1249 dediğinizi varsayalım. Buna da +2 -1 olarak yanıt 
vereceğim. Çünkü 2 adet doğru sayı doğru yerde,")
print("1 adet doğru sayı yanlış yerde.")
input("Hazır olduğunda <Enter>a bas.") # hit enter when ready


pick()  

print(sayı[0]+sayı[1]+sayı[2]+sayı[3])#testing for me

testpick()

tahmin_test()

print("Bir saniye, hesaplıyorum...")# calculating effect pause
time.sleep(3)

tahmin = str(tahmin)
sayı = str(sayı)
#below x a b y are not used. Was planned to be used but wasn't.
x = 0
a = 0
b = 0
d = 0
y = 0
dsdy = 0#right number right place variable
dsyy = 0#right number wrong place variable 1
dsyy1 = 0#right number wrong place variable 2
abc = 0#another variable to sum dsyy and dsyy1 variables

test_sayısı = [sayı[0], sayı[1], sayı[2], sayı[3]]# for me to see
print(test_sayısı)#for me to see

test_tahmini = [tahmin[0], tahmin[1], tahmin[2], tahmin[3]]#for me to see
print(test_tahmini)#for me to see

for d in range(0, 4):# test the corresponding respective digits for matches
    d = int(d)
    if sayı[d] == tahmin[d]:
        dsdy = int(dsdy) + 1

#print("dyds yok maalesef")
for d in range(1,4): # test the first three combinations for matched digits 
in wrong decimal places
    if sayı[0] == tahmin[d]:#test 
        dsyy1 = int(dsyy1) + 1
    else:
        continue

def sontest():# test all the remaining combinations, which I could not form 
into a logical loop so the below stupidity.
    global dsyy
    if sayı[1] == tahmin[0]:
        dsyy = int(dsyy) + 1
    else:
        dsyy = int(dsyy)
    if sayı[1] == tahmin[2]:
        dsyy = int(dsyy) + 1
    else:
        dsyy = int(dsyy)
    if sayı[1] == tahmin[3]:
        dsyy = int(dsyy) + 1
    else:
        dsyy = int(dsyy)
    if sayı[2] == tahmin[0]:
        dsyy = int(dsyy) + 1
    else:
        dsyy = int(dsyy)
    if sayı[2] == tahmin[1]:
        dsyy = int(dsyy) + 1
    else:
        dsyy = int(dsyy)
    if sayı[2] == tahmin[3]:
        dsyy = int(dsyy) + 1
    else:
        dsyy = int(dsyy)
    if sayı[3] == tahmin[0]:
        dsyy = int(dsyy) + 1
    else:
        dsyy = int(dsyy)
    if sayı[3] == tahmin[1]:
        dsyy = int(dsyy) + 1
    else:
        dsyy = int(dsyy)    
    if sayı[3] == tahmin[2]:
        dsyy = int(dsyy) + 1    
    else:
        dsyy = int(dsyy)    
    if sayı[0] == tahmin[1]:
        dsyy = int(dsyy) + 1
    else:
        dsyy = int(dsyy)    
    if sayı[0] == tahmin[2]:
        dsyy = int(dsyy) + 1
    else:
        dsyy = int(dsyy)    
    if sayı[0] == tahmin[3]:
        dsyy = int(dsyy) + 1    
    else:
        dsyy = int(dsyy)

sontest()
abc = int(dsyy1) + int(dsyy)    
print("+" + str(dsdy))
print("-" + str(abc))
input("Press <Enter> to continue")

print ("afferim len dümbük !")
quit()
```

Comment: You need to show a lot more effort than that. Pseudo code isn't going to cut it.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: I will translate the lang to english for all to understand. Give me 10 min or so.

Answer (score 0):

I used [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#counter-objects) in order to allow for repeated digits.

```
from collections import Counter

def compare(n, guess):
    not_matching_digits = Counter(guess) - Counter(n)
    matching_digits = len(n) - sum(not_matching_digits.values())
    right_place = sum(1 for i0, i1 in zip(n, guess) if i0 == i1)
    wrong_place = matching_digits - right_place
    return right_place, - wrong_place
```